# dataframe to html formatter (using Flask) to be applied to all columns

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

I am trying to display my dataframe on an HTML page (the app is on Flask framework), and as part of the display, I am using df.to_html function to do so.

Now this function (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) has the formatters argument which allows me to apply the formatting for a(specific) columns one by one.

However if i need to apply the formatting on all columns(number of columns will be dynamic, so i cant really list all column names) then how would i do it ?

The below code is an example code that helps to format 2 columns (Total and RATE), however there may not be 2 columns exactly with these names at all times.
And i want apply the formatting for all columns.

```
    return render_template("ABCD.html",
                   table_name = df.to_html(
                           formatters={ 
                       "TOTAL": lambda x:'{:,.2f}'.format(x),
                        "RATE": lambda x:'{:,.2f}'.format(x)},
     bold_rows = True, border =2,  index = False, justify = 'center',  na_rep =' '))
```

Comment: Do you want to apply the same formatting to each column?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander:  yes, that'll do

Comment: @JoshFriedlander : Assuming I only want to apply the formatting from the second to the last column of the dataframe, how will that change things ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
return render_template("ABCD.html",
               table_name = df.to_html(
                       formatters=[lambda x:'{:,.2f}'.format(x)] * df.shape[1],
                       bold_rows = True, border =2,  
                       index = False, 
                       justify = 'center',  
                       na_rep =' '))
```

Comment: Thanks @josh
And if I were to do it for all columns (except the first column), then how would it be ?
Thanks again

Comment: You need to give a format for the first column and add it to the list. The length of the list needs to equal the number of columns